# Conceptual question about computing colimits of sheaves using the sheafification functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, soft-question

Let $X$ be a topological space. Consider the category $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves on $X$ and natural transformations between sheaves.

It is well-known that colimits in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ are computed as follows: firstly, compute the colimit in the category $\mathrm{PSh}(X)$ of presheaves on $X$. Secondly, take the sheafification of that colimit in the category of presheaves.

In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are sheaves, then their coproduct is $(iA + iB)^\#$, where
$$i\colon \mathrm{Sh}(X) \to \mathrm{PSh}(X)$$
is the inclusion functor and
$$(-)^\#\colon \mathrm{PSh}(X) \to \mathrm{Sh}(X)$$
is it's left adjoint - the sheafification functor.

Does that fact that $(-)^\#$ is left adjoint to $i$ have something to do with the fact that colimits are computed using sheafification? I'm curious whether there's a general categorical fact about computing colimits using adjoint functors (or something like that) I'm missing. Also: is sheafification on morphisms, i.e., the function $$(-)^\#\colon \mathrm{Mor}(\mathrm{PSh}(X)) \to \mathrm{Mor}(\mathrm{Sh}(X)),$$
used in the construction of colimits in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$? That would be an indication that really the *functor* $(-)^\#$ is closely connected to colimits in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ (and not only the "object function"!).

Are there other examples of situations in which one constructs colimits using an adjoint functor (to an inclusion functor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Sh}{Sh} \DeclareMathOperator{Psh}{Psh}$Yes, the fact that $(-)^\#$ is a left adjoint is part of what is necessary to show that this is how colimits are computed. This is because left adjoints preserve colimits.

That is, consider any diagram $j : J \to C$ and any adjunction $f \dashv g : C \dashv D$. Suppose that $x \in C$ together with a natural transformation $\theta : j \to \Delta x$ is a colimit of $J$ ($\Delta x$ being the diagram sending all objects and arrows to $x$). Then $f(x)$ together with $f(\theta)$ is a colimit of the diagram $f \circ j$.

The other part of what is necessary is that $\Sh(X)$ is a reflective subcategory of $\Psh(X)$, meaning that the inclusion $i : \Sh(X) \to \Psh(X)$ is fully faithful. This is equivalent to saying that the counit of the adjunction, $\epsilon : (-)^\# \circ i \to 1_{\Sh(X)}$, is an isomorphism (this is a general categorical fact).

Combining these two facts means that if we have a diagram $j : J \to \Sh(X)$, we can take the colimit $x \in \Psh(X)$, $\theta : i \circ j \to \Delta x$. We can then sheafify to get a colimit $x^\# \in \Sh(X)$, $\theta^\# : (-)^\# \circ i \circ j \to \Delta x^\#$ of $(-)^\# \circ i \circ j$.

But we know that $(-)^\# \circ i \simeq 1$ via the natural isomorphism $\epsilon$, so this allows us to show that $x^\#$ together with $\theta^\# \circ (\epsilon \circ j)$ is a colimit diagram in $\Sh(X)$.

So the only relevant properties here are that $i : \Sh(X) \to \Psh(X)$ is fully faithful and has a left adjoint, and that certain colimits can be computed in $\Psh(X)$. This situation applies in many cases. For example, the Stone-Cech compactification shows that the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is a reflective category of the category of topological spaces. This allows the construction of all colimits in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Exactly the explanation I wanted! Thank you so much for your fantastic answer! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The general result is as follows (which can be found in almost every category theory textbook): Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a reflective subcategory of a category $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. the inclusion has a left adjoint $L : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$. Then, if a diagram $(X_i)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ has a colimit $\mathrm{colim}_i X_i$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $L(\mathrm{colim}_i X_i)$ is its colimit in $\mathcal{D}$. The proof is just one line: For $T \in \mathcal{D}$ we have natural bijections
$$\hom(L(\mathrm{colim}_i X_i),T) \cong \hom(\mathrm{colim}_i X_i,T) \cong \lim_i \hom(X_i,T). ~~ \square$$
Also, it is well-known that left adjoints only have to be defined on objects; the action on morphisms follows from the universal property. Specifically, for $X \in \mathcal{C}$ we have a universal morphism $X \to L(X)$ with $L(X) \in \mathcal{D}$, and a morphism $f : X \to X'$ is mapped to the unique(!) morphism $L(X) \to L(X')$ such that the evident square commutes.